# Как получить X-Auth-Key для yandex maps или как правильно использовать его для обращения к api-developer.tech.yandex.net

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Читаю документацию: https://yandex.ru/dev/developer-help/doc/api/auth.html
Там сказано, что получаю ключ после подключения API,скриншот ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В кабинете разработчика вижу свои ключи:[image: yandex ключи]

Но, когда пытаюсь сделать Http запрос для получения id проектов, мне возвращается 403я ошибка:
[image: 403я ошибка]

Почему у меня нету доступа? Или нужно другой ключ где то брать?

Comment: яндекс хочет денюх )))

Answer (score 1):

Всё оказалось просто, в API интерфейсах нужно было создать ключ для API Кабинета Разработчика, а я создавал для API Геокодера